# How to adjust the screen density for a Robolectric test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

I'm currently testing a fragment method in my app that is sensitive to the DisplayMetrics settings of the device it's running on.  How do you adjust the DisplayMetrics in a Robolectric test for a RobolectricTestRunner (please provide an example, if possible)?

Here's the gist of my simple test where I want to be able to control the screen's DisplayMetrics.

```
    @Test
public void whenMyFramentMethod_willWorkForDensity() {

    ...

    startFragment(fragment);

    //Results of this method will vary with different screen sizes.
    Assert.assertEquals(200, fragment.fetchAWidth());
}
```

Comment: Why would you like to test width? If it fails what should you do?

Comment: The useful portion of this test would be to assure that some method is taking screen density into account when measuring something. An obvious way to assure that is happening would be to set the screen density to something specific and verify that the method's result is multiplied by that factor.

Answer (score 3):

You should now use the @Config annotation to setup the environment:

```
@Config(qualifiers = "xhdpi")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on the `ShadowResources`:

```
@Test
public void shadow_resources_example(){
    final Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
    final ShadowResources shadowResources = Shadows.shadowOf(context.getResources());
    shadowResources.setDensity(2f); //2 == xhdpi for example
    assertEquals(20, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```